# What trinket should I start with, when should I switch and upgrade?

Tags: league-of-legends

I normally try to play every game like this (there are some exceptions, like Lee Sin, Jax, ... who gain extra mobility with wards):

1. Get [Warding Totem](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Warding_Totem) at beginning for extra vision (even as jungler! then i try to ward the river)
2. Once I hit level 9 or I get my [Sightstone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sightstone), I switch to [Sweeping Lens](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sweeping_Lens)
3. When I play against something invisible (Akali, Shaco, Evelynn, ...) or at least when I'm full built I upgrade it to [Oracle's Lens](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle%27s_Lens)

I never saw [Scrying Orb](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Scrying_Orb) in the game (which I fully understand)

**Is there something I should change with my trinket build order?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Warding Totem**

- Safe start, no matter what champion
- Gives you Defensive Map Control (sometimes offensive in Jungle)
- Free ward Jumps
- Buy this item at start 95% of the time

**Sweeping Lens**

- Safe to buy after you've finished your Sightstone
- Consider buying it against stealth champions (upgrade to Oracle's Lens for stealth detection)
- Sometimes a good Idea on junglers if you want an early dragon
- Can be bought if you are playing a Supporter that relies on Bush-Stealth
- Don't start with the item unless you're planning on camping a lane like crazy

**Scrying Orb**

- Can be used for scouting Nashor/Dragon
- Could be useful for Non-Skillshot High-Range casts (Nocturne, Caitlyn Ult)
- Generally avoid buying the Item in a serious game

## Detail

Usually you want to start with the warding Trinket since it's pretty much the safest and most useful trinket of the three at start. It gives you a free ward for either vision or sometimes even a free flash for champions with Friendly-Dash abilities (Katarina, Jax, Lee-Sin etc). When jungling it can also give you vision control for either more safety or better counterjungling.

The sweeping lens is a really strong Item but most of the time it's only good later in the game. A lot of people buy it as a jungler but usually you should avoid buying it at the beginning because if you buy it early the enemy will still spot you before you can clear the ward. The only time you can actually buy this at the beginning is if you play champions that rely on vision breaks of bushes (Thresh, Blitzcrank, Leona) but even there it's situational and most of the time an extra ward is a more decent start. You want to buy this item if you have a Sightstone as a supporter or for additional objective/jungle control as a jungler but that generally happens in the midgame. Another situation where you could buy it potentially is if you are facing Champions that rely on stealth (Twitch/Akali) but remember that you need the Full upgrade for 475 gold to obtain True Vision.

As you've already mentioned, the orb is a rather useless item. You should avoid buying it on Most champions and the only champions that could actually benefit from it are champions with high-range targeted abilites like Caitlyn or Nocturne. But usually it's still a better choice to take a ward on these champions.

Comment: so i'm doing everything perfect?

Comment: @PhilippSander well yes, if you're buying the Items the way you described in your question it's pretty safe and right. For it to be perfect you have to buy and upgrade situational ;)

Comment: well of course its situational, but i didnt want to mention every exception explicitly.

Comment: I disagree that the orb is useless. Its very good later in the game on adcs, as you use it for scouting, and making sure important brushes are safe before walking close enough to them to drop a ward in. If you watches the NA playoffs this weekend, you'll notice that in basically every game, both teams had atleast one scrying orb

Comment: @BenCraig This only occurs in extremely High Ranked 5v5 Play (and for whatever reason in Diamond and Challenger Tiers in Brazil). But the statistics about winrate and pickrate show that it's rather useles in Soloqueue, Normal games and Low Elo 5v5 Play. Just because someone does something in the LCS it doesn't mean it's good or bad per-se. It means they are building situational.